# react hooks useEffect update window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update state with the inner window height as I resize the screen. When I log the state height within the `useEffect` hook I get 0 each time however, when I log inside the `updateWindowDimensions` function the height value is updated as expected.

How can I update state with the new value each time?

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

const updateWindowDimensions = () => {
    const newHeight = window.innerHeight;
    setHeight(newHeight);
    console.log('updating height');   
};

 useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowDimensions);
     console.log("give height", height);
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is only being run one time, when the component mounts (because of the empty array `[]` you passed as the second argument)

If you simply log outside of it, you'll see your state value is being updated correctly

```
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateWindowDimensions = () => {
      const newHeight = window.innerHeight;
      setHeight(newHeight);
      console.log("updating height");
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", updateWindowDimensions);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateWindowDimensions) 

  }, []);

  console.log("give height", height);
```

Also you should move the declaration of that function inside the `useEffect` so it's not redeclared on every render

Comment: Ah yes - thank you. Still new to hooks - good to know about the empty array. This is meant to be used for unmounting correct?

Comment: Effects are run on after every render. That second argument is an array of values the effect depends on. Since your effect doesn't depend on any values, you can leave it empty. This will cause the effect to only run on mount

Comment: When working with window events, you may want to use the "cleanup"-functionality of `useEffect` by returning a function from your `useEffect` body to avoid memory leaks like so: `useEffect(() => { /*...*/ return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateWindowDimensions); });`

Answer (score 1):

The above Answer by @Galupuf won't work ideally, until you add updateWindowDimensions call below addEventListener:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", updateWindowDimensions);
updateWindowDimensions()
```

Because eventListener won't run this function until you resize.
so height will remain 0 until you resize.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late for answer, but we can define a hook for this purpose. In [here](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/) you can find a custom hook that update width and height of window on every resize.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future.