# React update value of window.innerWidth

Tags: reactjs

the width const return the width correctly but when i resize the window the value of width doesn't change. how can can i update it when viewport is resized.

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        setWidth(window.innerWidth)
    } else {
        setWidth('')
    }
}, [width])

console.log(width)
```

i tried putting the if statement in useEffect but obviously it's not working.

Comment: This will help you resolving your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642486/react-hooks-useeffect-update-window-innerheight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react hooks useEffect update window.innerHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642486/react-hooks-useeffect-update-window-innerheight)